# easy pass data from express to react

Tags: reactjs, express

So I'm trying to learn ReactJS but the documentation is terrible, after reading it I am even more confused than before.

I will keep it simple for the sake of learning:

This is my old approach:

Current:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});
```

So I get it with `{user}` in handlebars.

Now for react:

```
{this.props.user}
```

returns NULL. Seriously, what the ...? How to pass the variable easily?

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS is mostly used for single page applications, meaning that most data is fetched after the application is loaded. If you want to use ReactJS as a template engine with expressJS use [express-react-views](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views). Otherwise you need to prerender ReactJS with [react-prerender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-prerender) when using NodeJS.

But I guess what you really want to do is to read/watch a good ReactJS tutorial.

Here are some resources for you:

- [Learn React & Redux](https://frontendmasters.gitbooks.io/front-end-handbook-2017/content/learning/react-redux.html)
- [Simple React Development in 2017](https://hackernoon.com/simple-react-development-in-2017-113bd563691f)

Hope that brings you on track :)

Comment: Can you tell me why?